# Dask DataFrame from Csv, reads too many rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

I am moderately familiar with Pandas, but this is my first time using Dask.

When reading from a large CSV file (1 million rows), I get results from df.shape and df.column.value_counts that suggest I have over 200 Million rows! I have read in smaller dataframes with Dask and do not have this issue. Likewise, when I read in only 1000 rows from the large Csv, I do not have this issue.

```
df = dd.read_csv('product_locations_2022-09-19.csv',usecols=['custom_rp_code'], dtype={'custom_rp_code': 'object','supplier': 'float64'}, blocksize="10MB")

df.columns

df.custom_rp_code.value_counts().compute()
```

[image]

Proportionally, the value counts are correct, but rows must be being duplicated somehow.

Comment: At first glance, you pass `usecols=['custom_rp_code']` to use a single column then you specify the type of two collumns with `dtype={'custom_rp_code': 'object','supplier': 'float64'}` ?

Comment: also... and maybe this is just a longshot... maybe a pet peeve... but your cells have been executed all out of order. for example df was read in after you compute the shape. can you restart your kernel, run straight through to confirm this behavior is real, and then copy and paste your code and outputs as a formatted code block rather than an image? SO asks that you don't post images of data, code, or errors [for a variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) anyways